# Swift String overload behavior of '>'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I have a playground:

```
let astr = "A"
let bstr = "a"

astr > bstr

"A" > "a"
```

Output:
false for the first use of > and an error for the second one:

Playground execution failed: :69:5: error: ambiguous use of operator '>'
"A" > "a"
    ^
Foundation.>:1:6: note: found this candidate
func >(lhs: String, rhs: NSString) -> Bool
     ^
Foundation.>:1:6: note: found this candidate
func >(lhs: NSString, rhs: String) -> Bool

This is the drill down of the real problem I am having:

```
var team = ["Jane","Kate","George","Zulma"]
let sortedteam = team.sorted({ $0 > $1 })
```

This is giving me the same error.

Comment: I can't explain why but you can solve this by reversing the comparison: Replace `{ $0 > $1 }` by `{ $1 < $0 }`.

Comment: That's true... is weird. And the error it is giving is really not helpful. For the first part of the question the difference looks nonsense too. Tks for the Work around though

Comment: @MartinR For some reason it also works if you put an explicit `return` in there: `{ return $0 > $1 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the global sorted function instead, which doesn't have this issue:

```
var team = ["Jane","Kate","George","Zulma"]
let sortedteam = sorted(team, { $0 > $1 })
```

Alternatively you could remove some of the conciseness of the closure, so the compiler knows what types it's comparing.

```
var team = ["Jane","Kate","George","Zulma"]
let sortedteam = team.sorted({ (s1: String, s2: String) in s1 > s2 })
```

Comment: `Array` *has* a `sorted()` method, and actually `let sortedteam = team.sorted({ $1 < $0 })` compiles. So the real reason seems to be something else.

Comment: thanks Martin, I revised that part. That seems to indicate that it's likely a bug